# Определение кодировки или формата

Tags: кодировка

Приходит строка вида

> aSBkZWNlbWJlcgBlHwAAAHsL

Должна получиться 
**31 december**

Очень похож на Base64 -

> i decembere{

Никто не подскажет как получить выходной вариант?

Comment: Если это base64 - то надо сначала перевести в heх. Если не base64, можно создать base63 или 62, то по-моему только методом тыка `69 20 64 65 63 65 6d 62 65 72 00 65 1f 00 00 00 7b 0b`

Comment: А дальше, можно только угадывать что означает І с кодом 69h, возможно так закатали число 31. По крайней мере 69h = 105, код символа @ = 64, код буквы А = 65. Беру 64 потому что все любят кратность двойки. 105 - 64 = 41. Возможно для вычета взято 74. 105-74 = 31.... но это лишь догадки. И что за 7b 0b в хвосте - тоже можно только догадываться. Более реально установить закономерность можно если есть несколько случаев кодировке, на одном случае - гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Лучше сказать откуда это взято. Если это не тупо взлом непонятно чего, а какая-то извесная вещь - то думаю подскажут формат. Угадать формат по 18 байтам тут не получится.

Comment: О, ещё вариант. 1Fh = 31. Если это выцепили из СУБД, то  64 - маркер длинны строки, а 1F это и есть 31. Но это так догадки

Comment: @nick_n_a это задача, необходимо определить что делает программа и сделать такую же. Ясно одно, приходит json типа {"program":"aXBpbmVjb25lAGlwYXJ0cmlkZ2UAe5pl/QAAAJoL"}, и затем происходит какая - то манипуляция данными

Comment: А ещё подпись может стоять:)